# An unexpected error occurred on a send. TLS1.1 connection Error

Tags: vb.net, tls1.2

We have some old VB code on a server which is compiled and is making a web service call. The provider recently updated from TLS1.1 to TLS1.2 and that's when the code stopped working and we started getting the error message

> Underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred on a send

I am not very familiar with VB. Are there any changes we can make on the *Windows Server* so that the compiled code makes a connection via TLS1.2?

It took some time, but I've added the stack trace. I've edited it a bit for privacy:

Here is the error message:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Trace:
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>   at (...............).BeginSession(String Profile) in C:\Users...\Desktop.............................vb:line 146
>   at (................)RetrieveData(Int32 queueNumber) in   C:\Users(..................................).vb:line 475
>   at   (.................) in C:\Users(...................................)vb:line 121

Here's a part of the code where a webservice connection is made (line 146 in the stack above):

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("......BeginSession", RequestNamespace:="........com", ResponseNamespace:=".............com", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)> _
Public Function BeginSession(ByVal Profile As String) As String
  Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("BeginSession", New Object() {Profile})
  Return CType(results(0), String)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this just before the request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
```

I think it should work then.

Worked for me, when I had an error, though a bit different one.

Comment: I am getting an error saying Tls12 is not a member of 'System.Net.SecurityProtocolType'. I'll be researching it unless you have faced it earlier.

Comment: I have not, I believe 1.2 was added in .net4.5 so if you are using versions previous to that it could be why.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved.The steps I took was to upgrade the project by opening it in the latest version of Visual Studio (2017). I had a few errors upgrading mostly related to the solution file being read-only. I then changed the target framework of the project to 4.6.1.
After doing these changes and rebuilding the solution, the app seems to be working.